# How to toggle NetworkManager's "Use this connection only for resources on its network" option via command line

Tags: bash, network-manager, 17.04, routing, nmcli

At my work we have some test machines that we run scripts on via ssh. During the test we want to only have the machines access the local network through their Ethernet connection, but then would like to have them be able to access the Internet through the same interface for cleanup and data transmission after.

We can do this by going to each machine and toggling the `"Use this connection only for resources on its network"` option in the `network manager` > `IPv4 options` > `routes menu`, but it would be a lot more convenient to be able to add this into our test script.

I can find some similar questions that have to do with VPN connections, but I want to make sure I handle the routing correctly for the regular Ethernet interface. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 23):

You can use `nmcli` to do it, the key is `ipv4.never-default`:

```
nmcli connection modify enp3s0 ipv4.never-default true
```

- change `enp3s0` with your own connection name.
- use `false` or `true` to toggle between this config.

Comment: `enp3s0` is the device name, not the connection name. Use `nmcli device` to find out the connection name.

Comment: @Marduk I use `device name` as my connection names. That's what I prefer. The description states that you have to change it with your connection name :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was a bit confused.

Answer (score 6):

If you'd rather edit files directly, you can do that as well.

Navigate to `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` directory and find the connection you want. Open the network using `sudo nano MyNetwork`.

Once you have the file open, look for the `[ipv4]` section, and add `never-default=true`, like so:

```
[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto
never-default=true
```

If you also want IPv6 routes to be handled in the same way, add the same line to the `[ipv6]` section:

```
[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
ip6-privacy=0
method=auto
never-default=true
```

Save and quit the editor with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and then restart NetworkManager with the below to ensure that the changes are picked up:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

Reconnect to the network, and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the default route and they'll be accessible only from your lan subnet.

```
ip route delete default
```

And to add it back:

```
ip route add default via <you_gateway_ip_address>
```